# Soup.select method in python - how to choose only one score?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to display only first score of soup.select method, now i have this code:

```
score = soup.select('my_name a')
print(score)

urls = [tag['href'] for tag in score if 'href' in tag.attrs and "name" in tag['href']]
print(urls)
```

When bs finds only one score, it works very good. But how to choose only first score when i get more scores?

Now output is:

```
> [<a href="/name/adrian1021 "> Adrian </a>, <a href="/name/john.james"> John James </a>, <a href="/name/carol22 "> Carol Coat </a>]
> 
> ['/name/adrian1021 ', '/name/john.james ', '/name/carol22 ']
```

I want to extract only one score, for example output should be:

```
[/name/adrian1021 ']
```

Is that possible? I tried to work on this like on list but it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried `print(urls[0])`?

Comment: _I tried to work on this on list but it does not work_ Huh, how?

Comment: Yes i did it but i get information: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @noname Can you share the code and data for that? I think it just means that the search returned no results, which is unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to use `soup.select_one()` which finds only the first element that matches a selector.

So your score variable should be:

```
score = soup.select_one('my_name a')
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it works after few changes in code :) maybe you know is that any possibility to get a method for selecting not only first tag?

Comment: @noname `.select()` does that.

Comment: Oh i didn't precise my question, i mean for example only second element or only last element, always only one of them choosen by me.